# FTP Automatic Permission Change

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, permissions, server

I need to be able to ftp a file directly to a folder in ubuntu server 14.10 that will automatically change the permissions to 775. Is there a command or setting in the vsftpd config that will allow me to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Though your question would be better received on [su] or [sf].

Comment: Okay, I'll try there. Sorry for making the forums messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the vsftpd option `file_open_mode`:

> The permissions with which uploaded files are created. Umasks are
>   applied on top of this value. You may wish to change to 0777 if you
>   want uploaded files to be executable.
>
> Default: 0666

See the [`vsftpd.conf` man page](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's dirty but you could simply create a cronjob which sets the permissions in the ftp folder every let's say 5 minutes.

Comment: So there's no way I could just have everything put into a folder change to a certain permission?

Comment: The problem is that the user of your ftp server should no have the necessary permissions to change the uploaded files.

Comment: I'm using a service called FreeCMS to manage a website and it needs to be able to upload new files in order to work, so that's why it needs to change the permissions automatically. It's a new file that's being uploaded under different permissions. Is there a way to make all FTP uploads be a certain permission?